# Integral solution of $y^2=x^3-51$

Tags: number-theory, ideals, quadratic-forms

I have the following equation: $y^2 = x^3 -51$. I want to show that this equation has no integral solutions.

I found out that $x$ must be odd and that $\gcd(y,51)= 1$. But how can we finally show that there is no integral solution? (By contradiction I guess, but how exactly?)¨

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Title doesn't match the question. Have a look at the power of $x$ please.

Comment: For the equation in the body, $25^2 = 26^2  - 51$

Comment: In the case of exponent $3$, we have a mordell curve which is generally difficult to solve. If the exponent is $2$, there is a solution for $x^2-y^2=n$ , if and only if $n$ is not of the form $4k+2$. Since $51$ is odd, there must be a solution.

Comment: I throw the equation to an online CAS [magma](http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/calc/) using the command, `Q<x> := PolynomialRing(Rationals());
E00  := EllipticCurve(x^3-51);
Q00  := IntegralPoints(E00);
Q00;`. The elliptic curve $y^2 = x^3 - 51$ doesn't have any integral points.

Comment: @achillehui Yeah this is what the claim says...but why aren't there any solutions?

Comment: @StMan No idea. Magma uses the heavy machinery of elliptic curve to find all solutions if present. For this problem, there may be more elementary way to prove that but it is better to know there are actually no solutions before wasting time of proving anything....

Comment: Yeah you're right. But how can I prove  that there really aren't any integral solutions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-51})$ has class number $2$, it is easy to solve this. Firstly, note that $y$ is even and $x$ is odd.

Consider $$(y-\sqrt{-51})(y+\sqrt{-51}) = x^3$$
any prime ideal divisor of two terms on left must lie above $2$ or $3$ or $17$, since $x$ cannot be even nor multiple of $3$ nor $17$, the two terms are coprime.

Therefore $(y+\sqrt{-51})$ is the cube of an ideal, which must be principal from class number, so
$$y+\sqrt{-51} = \left(\dfrac{a+b\sqrt{-51}}{2}\right)^3$$
for integers $a,b$, which implies
$$3a^2b-51b^3 = 8$$
this has no integer solutions, so neither does the original.

Comment: *since $x$ cannot be even nor multiple of $51$* - sounds like $51$ is prime, just like $57$ (:

Comment: @WhatsUp  thank you for pointing out, corrected.

Comment: Note however that the Mordell-Weil group has rank $1$. This curve is in the database: https://www.lmfdb.org/EllipticCurve/Q/280908/s/1

Comment: @WhatsUp  Yes, though for curve rank $\geq 1$, there is no relation between integral points and rank. But my answer at least shows the torsion over $\mathbb{Q}$ is trivial.

Comment: Not totally irrelevant though. Knowing a set of generators for the Mordell-Weil group, there are effective bounds by Baker's method, which combined with LLL reductions may determine the set of integral points. Thus the key step in computing integral points is usually just the computation of the Mordell-Weil group, for which we unfortunately don't have an effective method...